# One object across many apps in django

Tags: python, django, import

Some time ago I started to learn python and I created commandline application that manages your home bar and cocktails recipes (you can add alcohol bottles to it, add recipes, check if you have ingredients to create given cocktail and so on) that uses sqlite3 database. Class called `BarmanShell` is kind of api of this app which contains every function user could use.

`__init__` of that class contains db connection and data validation based on xml files.

Now, as I'm learning django, I would like to reuse it in web version of this application. In this django project I have app `myshelf` that must use some `BarmanShell` functionality.

```
def myshelf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "GET":
       barman = BarmanShell()
       shelf = barman.getShelf()
       # do some things to create context based on shelf
```

`barman = BarmanShell()` could be done only once, not every GET request. But I cannot move it up from `myshelf_view` function

```
barman = BarmanShell()
def myshelf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "GET":
       shelf = barman.getShelf()
       # do some things to create context based on shelf
```

as it contains some sql queries and following error is produced:

```
SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.
```

Also, I cannot move its creation to `django_project/urls.py` and then import it in `myshelf/views.py`

```
barman = BarmanShell() # in urls.py
from django_project.urls import barman # in views.py
```

because it gives an error

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'barman' from partially initialized module 'django_project.urls' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Is there a way to crete that object only once and then just reuse it across django without big `BarmanShell` refactor such as making all functions static?

MWE of BarmanShell class:

```
class BarmanShell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SHELF
                                (ID   INTEGER,
                                 NAME TEXT     NOT NULL,
                                 QTY  INTEGER  NOT NULL,
                                 PRIMARY KEY(ID, NAME));''')
        self.conn.commit()

    def getShelf(self):
        return self.cur.execute("SELECT NAME, QTY FROM SHELF").fetchall()
```

Comment: It looks like you are calling another view in this view. Normally you do not do that, since views are wrapped in transactions. This is done to guarantee that the updates on the database are done in an atomic way.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem i'm not. views.py beside code above contains only
from django.shortcuts import render
from barmanshell.barmanshell import BarmanShell

Comment: it would help if you create a minimum example of BarmanShell() class to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Stepan done, you can use mwe to reproduce sqlite thread error.

Comment: @docp I think you should connect to the database via django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you properly connect your database everything should work,
this code works for me.

```py
#url.py
from django.db import connection
class BarmanShell(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cur = connection.cursor()
        self.cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SHELF
                                (ID   INTEGER,
                                 NAME TEXT     NOT NULL,
                                 QTY  INTEGER  NOT NULL,
                                 PRIMARY KEY(ID, NAME));''')

        self.cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO SHELF VALUES (1, 'Margo', 43);''')
        
    def getShelf(self):
        return self.cur.execute("SELECT NAME, QTY FROM SHELF").fetchall()

bn = BarmanShell()
print(id(bn))

urlpatterns = [    
    path('', views.myshelf_view, kwargs={'barman':bn}, name='myshelf_view'),
]
```

```py
#views.py
def myshelf_view(request, **kwargs): 
    print(id(kwargs.get('barman'))) 
    print(kwargs.get('barman').getShelf())
```

```
OUTPUT:
ID_OF_BARMAN_OBJECT
ID_OF_BARMAN_OBJECT
[('Margo', 43)]
```

The object creates just once.

Comment: just to be clear:
main problem was with self.conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")